# Can I schedule a job to run at midnight of each timezone, and how to let the proc know which timezone to process?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a job that I need to run at midnight for 7 timezones.  Is there a way to create a single schedule to do this in SQL 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2, that will tell the proc which timezone to process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server Agent isn't timezone-aware. You can figure out the time zone within the procedure by calculating:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE());
```

So you could set your schedule to run every hour, then within the procedure, check if the above results in one of your 7 timezones. If not, just return.

You could store the 7 timezones in a table so that when you add an 8th timezone you don't have to go change the procedure.

You may also need to go more granular depending on time zones you might support in the future - some are not a round number of n hours off UTC. For example [Newfoundland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_Standard_Time_Zone) is on the half hour: either 2.5 or 3.5 hours behind UTC, depending on Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: Is there any recommendable way how to handle DST (daylight savings time); without having table with timezones + their dates for switching to DST and then figuring out 'manually' if DST offset needs to be also applied. This seemd like reinventing the wheel over and over

Answer (score 2):

If you have a single SQL server that you will have to setup 7 separate scheduled calls - one for each timezone to run at midnight at this particular timezone. This is the BEST way of doing this.
It just occurred to me - did you mean that you want to run at midnight for each of the timezones (as I assumed) - i.e. at 7 different times, or at midnight in current timezone but process data for 7 separate timezones at once (in this case what is the difference between different timezones processing)?

Comment: run at midnight for each of the timezones

Comment: So, 7 different times == 7 executions.

Comment: @Jim no, it absolutely does not need to be 7 jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Just schedule your job to run stored procedure each hour. And in the stored procedure check `DATEPART(hh, GETUTCDATE())` to fixed list of midnights for needed timezones in UTC for example for the timezone +1 check if  `DATEPART(hh, GETUTCDATE())=(24-1)` for +2 check `DATEPART(hh, GETUTCDATE())=(24-2)`